# rich:pickList Add/Remove Button not rendering a4j:outputpanel on first click

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using richfaces 4.1 rich:picklist and need to render a4j:outputpanel on addition or removal of items in targetList. It renders outputpanel immediately on selecting Source/Target List elements but if directly click AddAll or RemoveAll button, output panel is not rendered on first click but renders onsecond click anywhere inside or outside screen.

Here is my code:

```
<rich:pickList value="#{myBean.selectedRegions}" 
valueChangeListener="#{myBean.regionChangeListener}"
switchByClick="true"  immediate="true">
<a4j:ajax event="additems" execute="@this" render="countryPanel" />
<a4j:ajax event="removeitems" execute="@this" render="countryPanel" />
<a4j:ajax event="sourceblur" execute="@this" render="countryPanel"/>
<a4j:ajax event="targetblur" execute="@this" render="countryPanel"/>
<a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="countryPanel" />
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.regions}" var="region"
    itemValue="#{region}" itemLabel="#{region.regionDesc}" />
<f:converter converterId="RegionConverter" />
</rich:pickList>
<a4j:outputPanel id="countryPanel" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to the latest RichFaces version should help. Also it would allow to simplify the code, you would need to specify only `change` event handler as the following issue has been fixed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12360